# Affine transformation implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, affinetransform

I am trying to implement affine transformation on two images.
First i find the matching pairs in both of the images. One of them is zoomed image and the other is a reference image. The pairs returned me co-efficients as :

```
     |1   0 |      | x |       |  1  |
A  = |      |  X = |   |   B = |     |
     |0   0 |      | y |       | 221 |   

The equation formed is X' = AX + B;

x_co_efficients[2] = (((x_new_Cordinate[2]-x_new_Cordinate[0])*(xCordinate[1]- xCordinate[0])) - ((x_new_Cordinate[1]-x_new_Cordinate[0])*(xCordinate[2] - xCordinate[0])))/
    (((xCordinate[1]-xCordinate[0])*(yCordinate[2]-yCordinate[0])) - ((xCordinate[2]-xCordinate[0])*(yCordinate[1]-yCordinate[0])));

x_co_efficients[1] = ((x_new_Cordinate[1]-x_new_Cordinate[0]) - (yCordinate[1]-yCordinate[0])*(x_co_efficients[2]))/(xCordinate[1]-xCordinate[0]);

x_co_efficients[0] = x_new_Cordinate[0] - (((x_co_efficients[1])*(xCordinate[0])) + ((x_co_efficients[2])*(yCordinate[0])));



y_co_efficients[2] = (((y_new_Cordinate[2]-y_new_Cordinate[0])*(xCordinate[1]- xCordinate[0])) - ((y_new_Cordinate[1]-y_new_Cordinate[0])*(xCordinate[2] - xCordinate[0])))/
    (((xCordinate[1]-xCordinate[0])*(yCordinate[2]-yCordinate[0])) - ((xCordinate[2]-xCordinate[0])*(yCordinate[1]-yCordinate[0])));

y_co_efficients[1] = ((y_new_Cordinate[1]-y_new_Cordinate[0]) - (yCordinate[1]-yCordinate[0])*(y_co_efficients[2]))/(xCordinate[1]-xCordinate[0]);

y_co_efficients[0] = y_new_Cordinate[0] - (((y_co_efficients[1])*(xCordinate[0])) + ((y_co_efficients[2])*(yCordinate[0])));
```

These are the equations i am used to finned the co-efficients from using the matching pairs. The equations are working fine for same images, for zooming image it is giving me those co-efficients. Now the problem is i have a 24 bit binary image, i want to implement affine transformation on that image with respect to reference. Now when i try to find the new co-ordinates of that image and change its current value to that co-ordinate I get a very much distorted image. which is should not get otherwise if the transformation is right.
Can Some one please have a look at the equations and also explain a little bit how to implement these equations on the second image.
My code is in C++. Thank you.
[image: This is my reference image]

My reference image is above.. and my comparison image is
[image]

The result i am getting is a distorted image with lines only.
[image]

**Edit 1**

I have now changed the solving method to matrices. Now i am getting the right output but the image i am getting after registration is like this..
Also i have to applied limit of 0 to 320*240 in the new co-ordinates to get the pixel value. Now my result is somewhat like this.
[image]

**EDIT 2**

I have changed the code and m getting this result without any black pixels. I am getting a little tilting.. have removed zoom effect in the given image though. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transformation matrix A is problematic. It destroys the y coordinate value and assigns 221 to all y coordinates

You can make the element at (2,2) in A just 1 and problem should be solved.

Comment: I tried making it 1 but it did not solve the problem.. I have improve on it a bit.. editing the above question please have a look. Thank you

Comment: these black lines stems from the transformation defects. When your original image points are mapped to the output image they have no a 1-to-1 relationship and you can handle this issue by reverse interpolation. What I mean is that in the output image, you take the coordinates of empty pixels, apply the reverse transformation and find the correspoing coodinates in the original image then just assign that pixel to the output pixel

Comment: Hi.. Please check out my edit.. I am getting a little tilting now.. Can you guide me here.. Thank you

Comment: During reverse interpolation, when you find the original pixel values, you will get float numbers, instead of directly casting these into ints, you can round them to nearest integers and you will get more accurate pixels.

Comment: Is there any function for it..?